# Convert string into TokenStream

Tags: rust, rust-macros, rust-proc-macros

Given a string (`str`), how can one convert that into a `TokenStream` in Rust?

I've tried using the `quote!` macro.

```
let str = "4";
let tokens = quote! { let num = #str; }; // #str is a str not i32
```

The goal here is to generate tokens for some unknown string of code.

```
let thing = "4";
let tokens = quote! { let thing = #thing }; // i32
```

or

```
let thing = ""4"";
let tokens = quote! { let thing = #thing }; // str
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. In the title you want to know, how to convert a String into a TokenStream, but in your text, you are complaining, that `str` is not an `i32`, which is a complet different question.

Comment: Not just that, what else would it be? You define it as a string literal by quoting it. try `let str = 4 as i32` and watch it turn into an `i32` literal in `quote!`.

Comment: This certainly might not be possible. I'll update the question with more details to clarify.

Comment: Your title still does not match your question.

Comment: I honestly feel like you're both using the wrong tool, and trying to solve a problem different to the one you have. Why are you trying to get a `TokenStream` from code you already know the structure of, and where does the additional data on types come from (even in your example, the type of `thing` could very well be an `u8`, or an `i16`, or anything else that `4` conforms to). What are you *actually* trying to parse?

Comment: @hellow I disagree. I’d like to know how to convert strings such as “(1,2)”, “func(1)”, “4” to TokenStreams.

Comment: I do think I’m going about this the wrong way though. I’m writing a macro and I’ve been managing the attributes to the macro by using regexes. I then want to go back to code during the generation step. It’s seeming like I should just work with the attributes I’m the TokenSteam that is provided to me.

Comment: What is the actual purpose of the macro? From this and your other question, it feels like the examples you give have very little to do with what you're actually attempting to do.

Comment: You haven't even specified where this `TokenStream` comes from. Do you mean [`proc_macro::TokenStream`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/proc_macro/struct.TokenStream.html) or [`proc_macro2::TokenStream`](https://docs.rs/proc-macro2/0.4.24/proc_macro2/struct.TokenStream.html), or some other one?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> how can one convert [a string] into a `TokenStream`

Rust has a common trait for converting strings into values when that conversion might fail: [`FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html). This is usually accessed via the [`parse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse) method on `&str`.

## [`proc_macro2::TokenStream`](https://docs.rs/proc-macro2/0.4.24/proc_macro2/struct.TokenStream.html)

```
use proc_macro2; // 0.4.24

fn example(s: &str) {
    let stream: proc_macro2::TokenStream = s.parse().unwrap();
}
```

## [`proc_macro::TokenStream`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/proc_macro/struct.TokenStream.html)

```
extern crate proc_macro;

fn example(s: &str) {
    let stream: proc_macro::TokenStream = s.parse().unwrap();
}
```

You should be aware that this code cannot be run outside of the invocation of an actual procedural macro.