# How to concatenate token right after a variable within `quote!` macro?

Tags: rust, token, concatenation, rust-macros

```rust
use quote::quote;

fn main() {
    let name = "foo";
    let res = quote!(#name bar);
    println!("{:?}", res.to_string());
}
```

The above code prints `"\"foo\" bar"`. Please try running it [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bca5a157e92c39d673b34b585edc12ce) on Rust Playground.

How to adjust it to make the single ident out of the variable part and constant suffix?

I want to use the `quote!` returned value in a derive macro. How to get rid of the double quote characters?

Comment: Yes. You are right. Sorry I didn't describe my question properly. I will update my question.

Comment: I found it helpful reading this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54165117/convert-string-into-tokenstream

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you only need to quote bar, how about combining the usage of `quote!` and `format!`?

```
use quote::quote;

fn main() {
    let name = "foo";
    let res = format!("{} {}", name, quote!(bar));
    println!("{:?}", res.to_string());
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=772c8b1c0d4a130d3c585a2e695e5d7a).

If you need the extra quote in the result:

```
use quote::quote;

fn main() {
    let name = "foo";
    let res = format!("\"{}{}\"", name, quote!(bar));
    println!("{:?}", res.to_string());
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=13b4b436627639ca49ceb5127d865dde).

Comment: Sorry. I think I didn't describe my question properly. I have update my question. Thanks for replying.

Comment: My case is a bit more complicated than what I described, but using `format!` first to concat and then put the result `&str` in `quote!` works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I found the extra part of solution that I need on top of Psidom's answer in this [blog](https://rendered-obsolete.github.io/2018/12/03/rust_derive_macros.html).

```rust
use quote::quote;
use syn;

fn main() {
    let foo = "foo";
    let foobar = syn::Ident::new(&format!("{}bar", foo), syn::export::Span::call_site());
    let q = quote!(#foobar);
    println!("{}", q);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cc691883ab93d71028ba6eda002b5878).